# Pyramid-debugging a resource cannot be found error

Tags: python, pyramid, paster

What are possible causes of "The resource could not be found" error in Pyramid?

From my limited exeperiece debugging my Pyramid app, errors with routes and Python syntax error trigger a more explicit error message.

Is there a way to get the development server to trace a request (similiar to the way running a rails server does it)? I tried running paster in verbose mode, but am not getting any more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So that's a `HTTPNotFound` error, which Pyramid has a debugging option for to help you out.

https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.2-branch/narr/viewconfig.html#notfound-errors

Comment: the link has gone bad, can you post the new location for this documentation?

Comment: I have fixed the broken link but it's still to the older documentation.